# To be or not to be Banach? That is the question.

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

On the set $H^1_0((0,2))$ we put the following norms.

$$\|u\|_a^2= \int_{[0,2]}(u')^2.$$ 
$$\|u\|_b= \|u\|_\infty.$$
$$\|u\|_c= \|u\|_{L^2}.$$

Is $H^1_0((0,2))$ Banach with any of these norms?

Comment: The first is a norm, thanks to the Poincaré inequality.

Comment: I'm not asking if it's a norm, I'm asking if it's complete with these norm.

Comment: Sorry, I mean that it is a norm equivalent to the standard one. Hence it is complete.

Comment: neither the 2nd nor the 3rd.

Comment: How do I prove it?!

Comment: I do not know if this is useful, but $H_0^1(0,2)$ is continuously embedded both into $L^2(0,2)$ and into $L^\infty(0,2)$. The second and the third norm are the natural norms of these spaces.

Comment: Trivial matter: I won't do it, but could you kindly add a "To" to the beginning of the title?  It's just so unidiomatic without it. :-)

Comment: What is yellow and complete? ..A Bananach space. ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: by the Sobolev embedding theorem, if $H_0^2(0,2)$ were complete under either the second or the third norm, then the usual norm would be equivalent to either the $L^\infty$ norm or to the $L^2$ norm. Can you find counterexamples to this?